# Java "Reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm not exactly new to programming, but for some reason I cannot get past this issue.  I'm writing a method, and keep getting the "reached end of file while parsing" compiler error.  Normally this happens when you forget a }, but this method only has two sets of brackets, and I'm not missing either close.  Could anyone point out why I'm getting this error?

```
 public class Locations{
    //member variables
    static int totalNumberOfRooms = 0;
    int numberOfExits;
    //pointers to each exit
    String roomGeneralDescription;
    String roomDescription;


    //member methods
    String getRoomGeneralDescription(){
        return this.roomGeneralDescription;
    }    

    String getRoomDescription(){
        return this.roomDescription;
    }
    //constructor to more easily create objects
    public Locations(int exit, String description, String generalDescription){
    totalNumberOfRooms += 1;
    numberOfExits = exit;
    roomDescription = description;
    roomGeneralDescription = generalDescription;
    }
    //default constuctor
    public Locations(){
        totalNumberOfRooms += 1;
    }

    //generates the given number of Locations obejcts, with pointers stored in a returned 
    //array.
    Locations[] createLocations(int x){
        int iterate = 1;
        int loopMax = x;
        Locations[] arrayOfLocations = new Locations[x -1];
        while (iterate <= loopMax){
            int index = iterate -1;
            arrayOfLocations[index] = new Locations();
            iterate += 1;
        }
        return arrayOfLocations;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else you're adding to the class?

Comment: Can u post full class?

Comment: compilers go stupid when it goes to syntax (ironically), so it may point to the wrong part of the code while error lies elsewhere

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code you posted is responsible for the issue.

Comment: I'm using netbeans, and it highlighted the end } of the createLocations method.  I've added the full class as requested.

Comment: Then you are missing a bracket no?

Comment: If you really really copied full class, then you're missing the bottom bracket which closes `Locations` class, else then do `ctrl + A` then copy-paste it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace `}` at the end of your file.

```
    Locations[] createLocations(int x){
        int iterate = 1;
        int loopMax = x;
        Locations[] arrayOfLocations = new Locations[x -1];
        while (iterate <= loopMax){
            int index = iterate -1;
            arrayOfLocations[index] = new Locations();
            iterate += 1;
        }
         return arrayOfLocations;
    }
} // YOU NEED TO ADD A CLOSING BRACE TO FINALIZE THE CLASS DEFINITION
```

**Update:** Even though the closing brace was the solution, I couldn't help but notice at how your `createLocations` method is actually written. It's an odd way to do an array allocation.  I'm not even sure what you have will run without crashing because the array is allocated to be of size `[x-1]`. In any case, here's a more clean solution to creating an array in Java. I hope this helps!

```
    Locations [] createLocations(int count) {

        Locations [] arrayOfLocations = new Locations[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            arrayOfLocations[i] = new Locations();
        }

        return arrayOfLocations;
    }
} // YOU NEED TO ADD A CLOSING BRACE TO FINALIZE THE CLASS DEFINITION
```

Comment: UGH!!!! I was so focused on the method I didn't even notice that.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Did it compile without a brace?

Comment: @shadowfox - I also used this as an opportunity to show you a cleaner way to do an array allocation. See my updated answer above. I hope this helps.